# Simple implementation of a set for ints in C

Tags: c, set, hashtable

I was wondering about a simple data structure for a set with O(1) lookup time. For detection of duplicate values in an unsorted linked list let's say.

The best I can come up with is a bool array, wherein the index stands for the value of the number. But this can have very high space complexities depending on the range. A red-black tree gives O(logn) time complexity.

Is there an alternative method, hash-table implementation of some kind, that can help me here? 
The simpler the better.

Comment: What is the range of possible values ? If it's not too big then a packed array of bits might be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory every set of `int` implementation is going to have `O(1)` complexity lookup time.  This is because there are a finite number of distinct `int` values, so there is an upper bound to the size of your set.

So even if the lookup time for a tree is `O(logN)`, in the case of integers that N has a maximum value, say N <= k.  *log k* is a constant, so your operation has an upper bound of a constant lookup time.  That is to say... **no matter how slow your algorithm is, it's faster than it would be with INT_MAX + 1 values**

In my experience, when people ask for constant-time set lookup, they really just want hashes.  This effectively reduces the size of *k* (at the cost of memory).  Your bool array idea is an extreme case, reducing *k* to 1.

Maybe what you want is just a *fast* set implementation?  If this is for academic purposes, then I'd suggest finding out what your professor wants.

Comment: So I see that a hash table is the best bet here. http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/11/13/fast-sets-of-integers/

Comment: *"In theory every set of `int` implementation is going to have O(1) complexity lookup time."* - you're trying to be too clever and ending up with nonsense.  The complexity describes the shape of the performance curve as N increases... for almost all actual implementations that shape will be well enough established by the time you have 4 billion elements to differentiate O(1) from many other complexities, even if subtler differences like say O(log(logN)) vs simply O(logN) may be harder to be certain of.

Answer (score 2):

You have an inherent space vs. time tradeoff here.  To ensure at most O(1) operations are required to test set membership, you need a data structure of at least O(n) size.  An array of `bool` could do it, or you could build a bitset out of an array of, say, `unsigned int` (I have done this for sets reaching to a few thousand members).  If you expect the sets to be sparsely populated relative to the range of their elements' values, then a hash table could keep you at the O(n) space level (whereas the space required for an array-based solution scales with element range).

Comment: Thanks. This article helped too - http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/11/13/fast-sets-of-integers/